# Setting Cookie with Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have a php page with a form, that has a button. When the button is clicked, a jquery function is run, which performs some validation tests, then submits the form using ajax. In the php script run by ajax, a cookie is set. Immediatly after the cookie is set, I then try to get the cookie value, which I echo from the script and spit out in the success function of the ajax request. The cookie value hasn't set.

Code is as follows.

**mainpage.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        $('#submit_compare_stage1').click(function()
        {
            //Validation stuff

            if (passed_validation)
            {
                var form_data = $('#compare_form').serialize(); //Collect query details into a form

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/process_compare.php",
                    data: form_data,

                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    },

                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        //Error stuff
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="compare_form" id="compare_form" action="">              
    ....

    <button id='submit_compare_stage1' name='submit_compare_stage1'>Next</button>
</form>
```

**process_compare.php**

```
<?php
    //MySQL Stuff

    makeCookie('cs', '2');

    echo 'hi' . getCookie('cs', false);

    echo "success";

    function makeCookie($name, $contents, $length = 3600)
    {
        // Create a new cookie
        setcookie($name, $contents, time() + $length, '/');
    }

    function getCookie($name, $delete = true) 
    {
        // Return the contents of a cookie and delete it if requested

        $contents = $_COOKIE[$name];

        if($delete) {
            setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600, '/');
            setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600);
        }

        return $contents;
     }
?>
```

The ajax request is posting alert messages saying "hisuccess" so the cookie isn't being set.

I'm not sure if it's because the page needs refreshing or something else, but I do know the code used to work when we had a regular submit the form using action="/process_compare.php" and an iframe to put results into.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did u try by simply running the script (server side) if any cookie is generated ?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. It is definitely running the script because it is printing the echo 'success' bit.

Comment: I meant your process_compare.php directly without ajax and try echo the cookie if its there. The path you have set correctly as / which should be accessible across the domain.

Comment: Why are you still using cookies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cookie is sent as a header of the response. In the `data` argument, you get the body of the response, not the headers.

It seems, that the headers of the response, you get from [`getResponseHeader()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`MDN - getAllResponseHeaders()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders%28%29), do not include the `Set-Cookie` headers.

But the cookies are handled transparently by the browser. So, in order to access the cookies, you can use the [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) property

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
        var cookies = [];
        if (document.cookie)
            cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');

        // do something with the cookies
    },
});
```

or use the [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin available at [github](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So what do I need to add to my ajax code to make the cookie readable by the rest of the program at a later date?

Comment: Sorry, when I actually tested it, the variable cookie comes back with null :(

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith I tested this myself and can confirm the missing cookie headers. Right now, the only way I see is using `document.cookie`, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why that works, but it just does :)